# Data table in LWC

Tags: lightning-datatable, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to achieve this in the data table in LWC? If yes please share some reference. If I select any rows under any category like the colour scheme and if I click save it should save.
Please see the attached screenshot

How to handle the duplicate in the attached screenshot you could see category is duplicated and my data table is also duplicated. how to show only category values in the data table instead of showing all ?

```
    <template>
       </template>
```

Comment: Without knowing what your data looks like, we don't have enough information to assist you with this latest edit. Please include the relevant Apex code.

Answer (score 1):

As a single data table, no. There's no allowance for headers. But it could be written as a list of cards:

```
 <template for:each={sections} for:item="section">
   <lightning-card key={section.id} icon-name="custom:custom11">
     <h1 slot="title">{section.title}</h1>
     <lightning-datatable columns={columns} data={section.data} key-field="id">
     </lightning-datatable>
   </lightning-card>
 </template>
```

Other similar designs might be what you're looking for as well; without code, I don't know exactly what you're looking for, but it should be easy from here.

To actually save the values, query the values from the tables:

```
let selected = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-datatable')].map(table => table.getSelectedRows()).flat().map(row => row.value);
```

This may not be precisely correct, but should get you started.

Comment: Can't believe I haven't seen `Array.prototype.flat()` before... could have saved me a few lines here and there.

Comment: @sfdcfox i have tried your approach but I'm getting duplicated category with values.Please help me out.Thanks in Advance

Comment: @sfdcfox sir i have updated the Apex code also basically I'm trying to display the Option  Category name in header with the relevant Category information inside data table.Thanks for your Quick response.Please help me further

Comment: @sfdcfox how to get the drafted values without having the onSave event or save button in LWC?

Comment: @grey123 Just read `draftValues` from the table components. I can see why you're having a problem, I guess; you have just a normal list of elements, but you're trying to make a list of lists. You need to either transform it in Apex, or transform it on the client.

Comment: @sfdcfox In the draftValue i couldn't get the Id of the Selected Rows because i gave Supress-bottom-bar and i tried to save via custom button.How to get draftValue with the recorded in LWC data-table?

Comment: @sfdcfox how to get draftvalues with RecordId of the selected rows in data-table?

Comment: @grey123 It should be included in the draftValues property regardless of suppress-bottom-bar.